# JSON requests get specific value from dict Python

Tags: python, json, websocket, python-requests

I'm trying to use this code from YouTube to detect a specific username in a Discord chat. If the username is, say "123" then print that as **"Found: 123"**. Tried different ways to no avail.

Here's my full code:

```
import websocket 
import json
import threading
import time

def send_json_request(ws, request):
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))

def receive_json_response(ws):
    response = ws.recv()
    if response:
        return json.loads(response)

def heartbeat(interval, ws):
    print("Heartbeat begin")
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)
        heartbeatJSON = {
            "op": 1,
            "d": "null"
        }
        send_json_request(ws, heartbeatJSON)
        print("Heartbeat sent")

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encording=json')
event = receive_json_response(ws)

heartbeat_interval = event['d']['heartbeat_interval'] / 1000
threading._start_new_thread(heartbeat, (heartbeat_interval, ws))

token = "tokenhere"
payload = {
    'op': 2,
    "d": {
        "token": token,
        "properties": {
            "$os": "windows",
            "$browser": "chrome",
            "$device": "pc"
        }
    }
}

send_json_request(ws, payload)

while True:
    event = receive_json_response(ws)
    try:
        print(f"{event['d']['author']['username']}: {event['d']['content']}")
        print(event)
        op_code = event('op')

        for specific in event:
            if specific['d']['author']['username'] == "123":
                print(f'Found: {specific}')
            else:
                print("Not found")

        if op_code == 11:
            print("Heartbeat received")
    except:
        pass
```

Code that doesn't work (but no errors):

```
for specific in event:
            if specific['d']['author']['username'] == "123":
                print(f'Found: {specific}')
            else:
                print("Not found")
```

What seems to be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Showing us the output this code is generating would help.

Comment: shouldn't it be print(f'Found: {specific['d']['author']['username']}') ?

Comment: This code basically prints the following: 123(username): content. My added code doesn't print anything.

Comment: @BemwaMalak, let me try that.

Comment: Can you be more specific what it doesn't work means?

Comment: @BemwaMalak - it didn't work...

Comment: @Cassano - what did it print?

Comment: @SimonHawe, the "Code that doesn't work (but no errors):" part in my post...

Comment: @BemwaMalak - it printed nothing when I sent a message in the chat (it should detect my username i.e. "123").

Comment: Is there no event? Does it raise an exception that you just catch without printing anything? There are various ways to say it doesn't work.

Comment: The entire code works, but the extra part that I added - which is to detect a specific username in a chat when they send a message - this specific part doesn't work as in no errors, but doesn't work.

Comment: Check the contents of `event` after you receive the json response, as in print it in order to see exactly what it contains.

Comment: It's great that you isolated the code you assume is problematic. Why not just add the full error message in the question as well? That would help everyone analysing what is going on. Feel free to checkout the guidlines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @cesarv - I edited the output of "print(event)" - please check.

Comment: @blurryroots - there is no error. The code just doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @Cassano, according to websocket's library documentation (https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#websocket._core.WebSocket), the `recv()` method returns a string, and you're treating it as a json object and trying to access it as such. Because of this, your code is throwing an exception that you're simply ignoring (`pass`). Remove the `try:`, `except:` and `pass` lines and verify, please.

Comment: I found the solution. I was doing it all wrong with "for" loop. Thank you everyone who tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have been using ***for*** loop. I tried the below code, and it worked. It was such a simple mistake:

```
specific = event['d']['author']['username']
if specific == "123":
    print(f"Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```